# Hey! I wanna save in ExternalStoragePublic file which I receive from the internet, but I really stuck. May you help me with code?

Tags: android, save

```
url = "http://r8---sn-03guxaxjvh-3c2r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire&mn=sn-03guxaxjvh-3c2r&ip=212.113.45.145&source=youtube&mm=31&mv=m&mime=video%2Fmp4&mt=1505092537&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=685000&dur=2223.728&id=o-AM9pUI9o5NsL8P-jGi5-w17xJOo-VVQ-TrWlMZaV17cp&key=yt6&lmt=1499875418101464&signature=4AACC08B22F2F1F343F5A044188CD751A6AD2F08.A7BA661DDC07639A7E414169226A35A700888AF3&ms=au&ei=HOS1WezYFZfq7gT40rnoAw&itag=22&pl=22&expire=1505114236&ratebypass=yes&title=Gothic+Rock+-+Dark+Music";


            streamPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                streamPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                streamPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            streamPlayer.start();`
```

my question is how to store on a device my streamPlayer object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
  try {
      URL u = new URL(url);
      URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
      int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

      DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new                         
        FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
  } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
  return; // swallow a 404
  } catch (IOException e) {
 return; // swallow a 404
  }
}
```